# Returning Null Value - Coalesce and ISNULL

Tags: sql, presto

I may be having a brain fog, but if I have below:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(Address.Info,''), 'Invalid')
```

Which gives me the value of invalid for all fields in my info column that have an empty space,
if I used **ISNULL** instead of **COALESCE** would it give me the same result? I cannot access a sql engine currently so just wanted to sanity check. Thanks!

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(Address.Info,''), 'Invalid')
```

Comment: Short answer: yes. But COALESCE is Standard SQL and both should also return *Invalid* for any number of blanks.

Comment: I am unsure that Presto supports `ISNULL()`. If `COALESCE()` does what you want, why do you want to change to something else?

Comment: It does, but I wanted to know the difference in some engines if ISNULL supported for knowledge purposes, thanks!

Comment: Presto does not support `ISNULL()`.

Comment: There are three functions with that behaviour in different DBMSs that take two arguments and return the second if the first is NULL: `NVL()`, `ISNULL()` and `IFNULL()`. With two arguments, `COALESCE()` has the same behaviour. But `COALESCE()` can take a variable number of arguments and returns the first that is not NULL. Makes it more flexible, but a trifle slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two expressions should be equivalent in e.g. Oracle, which supports these functions.

Presto does support the standard [`coalesce()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#coalesce). It does not have `isnull` function though. See more at https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html